# How to train tesseract for Right to Left languages

Tags: c#, opencv, ocr, tesseract, emgucv

i am trying to convert images to text using Tesseract OCR text written on images in balochi

(balochi is much like persian language)

i have created a Program which reads English text from images .. now i want to train it for balochi ..
what are the basics to train the Tesseract engine for right to left languages ..

is there any tool that can create traning data (Freeware / Shareware)

Here is my program .. waiting for your nicest suggestions .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.OCR;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace ReadingImageText
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Tesseract OCRz = new Tesseract("tessdata","eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY);

        private static Rectangle deviceN = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
        public static System.Drawing.Bitmap img = new Bitmap(deviceN.Width, deviceN.Height);
        System.Drawing.Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        Image azeem;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OCRz.Recognize(new Image<Bgr, byte>(img));
            richTextBox1.Text = OCRz.GetText();
            String text = OCRz.GetText();
            Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\azeemhassni\recognized_" + unixTimestamp + ".inp", text);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files (*.*) | *.*";
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = makeItImage(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }


        public Image makeItImage(String filePath)
        {
            Image newImage = Image.FromFile(filePath);
            img = (Bitmap) newImage;
            return newImage;

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: could you please share some real images of your studied case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it does not matter that your language is R->L or L->R, tesseract needs to train the patterns of languages (characters, symbols, or even a pattern of connected characters as arabic language), so the very important thing is to define the patterns exist in your particular language, to be recognized in the step of make box of tesseract. You may need to create an algorithm to segment the characters if there are connected patterns. once you have separated patterns, you can start training phase,

[Here](http://blog.cedric.ws/how-to-train-tesseract-301) is a tutorial explaining how to train your own language.
I suggest that you install [jTessBoxeditor](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html), that help you well in training your patterns, it has a GUI interface letting you train your own dataset

or

have a look at this one (i did not test it) sunnypage.ge/en
http://lib.psnc.pl/Content/358/PSNC_Tesseract-FineReader-report.pdf

Comment: @Azi Baloch , let me know about your progress, we may exchange some ideas

Comment: the first line, "here" is not valid

Comment: The link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

For RTL languages, you'd have to modify the `unicharset` file, specifically the direction of each character.

http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn-history/r719/trunk/doc/unicharset.5.html

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=811

Answer (score 0):

Ow! you have to train it to get .traineddata for your specific language.. Try this trainer if you want https://code.google.com/p/serak-tesseract-trainer/ or http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html.

Comment: thank's for the nice tool. i will try it .